# how to log transformation works, In what case we need to do log transformation

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, data-science-model

I am a newbie to machine learning, I am doing binary classification problem, I have some data, IN that data one of the columns having some float data. I plot data, The Data looks like this [image]

My column data like this:

```
([2.74646723e-02, 5.76427453e-02, 1.73579841e-01, 1.18747751e-01,
       1.02233936e-01, 5.79734106e-02, 1.11239703e-01, 9.84410103e-02,
       2.22469681e-01, 5.49779719e-02, 3.86586659e-02, 8.98826138e-02,
       1.00000000e+00, 4.17708100e-02, 3.69567120e-03, 6.10758293e-02,
       6.42366008e-02, 4.16152028e-02, 6.54717330e-02, 7.01204983e-02,
       2.98104510e-01, 1.64437918e-01, 4.88801144e-02, 6.12217111e-02,
       5.08738317e-02, 2.85733737e-02, 7.78230552e-02, 5.27216673e-02,
       4.49413069e-02, 1.29776412e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.30223783e-01,
       5.14184570e-02, 5.55225971e-02, 6.69889033e-02, 7.62183558e-02,
       4.86078018e-02, 9.40742830e-02, 2.07200724e-01, 5.98017953e-02,
       6.45964424e-02, 4.52719722e-02, 1.30603075e-01, 7.47789891e-02,
       6.06381841e-02, 4.21112008e-02, 3.97770930e-03, 2.72896142e-01,
```

After That I applied Log transformation, data getting infer values and all in negative  values , Please help me What should I do.

Comment: You can use thresholding instead of log transformation if you are doing binary classification.

Comment: Negative values of log(x) is not a problem, all log(x) where 0<x<1 are negative. The problem would be with x<=0. If you hate negative numbers, you may use -log(x) or log(1+x) transformation.